# ReactJS. Auto scroll to pdf page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The page contains a pdf slideshow. When clicking on a pdf page, a modal window opens with all pages and scrolls on it. I need automatically scroll to the page by the number that the user clicked.

For example, if the user clicked on page number 7. On Modal, the scroll will be on this page.

I use "react-scroll". Code example:

```
renderProject = () => {
    const {name, description, team, uploadPdf} = this.props.project;
    const {pageNumber, numPages} = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="section-project-extended">
          <div className="top-title">{name}</div>
          <div className="section-project-extended-wrapper">
            <div className="left-content-block">
              <div className="description">{htmlEncode(description)}</div>
              {uploadPdf && uploadPdf.secure_url ? (
                <div>
                  <div className="pdf-slide-nav">
                    {this.ArrowData.map((item, index) => (
                      <NavArrow {...item} key={index}/>
                    ))}
                    <a
                      className="full-width-btn"
                      href={uploadPdf.secure_url}
                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                      target="_blank"
                    ><img src={fullWidthIcon} alt=""/></a>
                  </div>
                  <Document
                    file={uploadPdf.secure_url}
                    onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                    loading={<LoadingMessage message="Loading pdf file.."/>}
                  >
                    <Link
                      offset={-100}
                      to={`#page-${pageNumber}`}
                      spy={true}
                      smooth={true}
                      duration={800}
                    >
                      <div className="zoom-pdf-page"
                           onClick={this.toggleZoomModal}>
                        <Page loading={<LoadingMessage message="Loading pdf page.."/>} renderAnnotationLayer={false}
                              renderTextLayer={false} pageNumber={pageNumber}/>
                      </div>
                    </Link>
                  </Document>
                  <div className="center-page-number">Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</div>
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            {team.length ? <Team team={team}/> : null}
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.zoomModal ? (
          <ModalDocument closeBtn={this.imgZoomRemove}/>
        ) : null}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
```

Sample code of a modal window with pdf pages and scroll:

```
class ModalDocument extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null
  };

  componentDidMount(numPages) {
    this.setState({numPages});
    pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({numPages}) => {
    this.setState({numPages});
  };

  render() {
    const {uploadPdf} = this.props.project;
    const {closeBtn} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="darken-center-wrapper">
        {uploadPdf && uploadPdf.secure_url ? (
          <Document
            file={uploadPdf.secure_url}
            onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
            loading={<LoadingMessage message="Loading pdf file.."/>}
          >
            {Array.apply(null, {length: this.state.numPages}).map((val, index) => {
              return index + 1;
            }).map((pages, i) => (
              <div id={`page-${pages}`}
                   key={i}>
                <Page
                  loading={<LoadingMessage message="Loading pdf page.."/>}
                  renderAnnotationLayer={false}
                  renderTextLayer={false}
                  pageNumber={pages}
                />
              </div>
            ))
            }
          </Document>
        ) : null}
        <div onClick={closeBtn} className="close-btn">
          <img src={closeIcon} alt="close-icon"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your PDF document, you can make sure to keep in memory [DOM references of the pages you render](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Then you can use [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to scroll to a given page using the references you previously retrieved.

For example:

```
// In your constructor
this.refs = this.state.numPages.map(() => React.createRef())

// Later in your render function
{Array.apply(null, {length: this.state.numPages}).map((val, index) => {
  return index + 1;
}).map((pages, i) => (
  <div id={`page-${pages}`
    ref={this.refs[i]}
    key={i}>
    <Page
      loading={<LoadingMessage message="Loading pdf page.."/>}
      renderAnnotationLayer={false}
      renderTextLayer={false}
      pageNumber={pages}
      />
  </div>
))

// When you want to scroll to a specific page
this.refs[2].scrollIntoView(); // Scroll to page 3
```